# Where is the single-parameter version of function sub() defined in SafeMath?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, uint256, safemath

I'm going through the [Ethernaut challenges](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/) to learn Solidity, and in [challenge 3 ("Coin Flip")](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x4dF32584890A0026e56f7535d0f2C6486753624f), they show the following code which subtracts 1 from the current block number:

[image]

I assumed that this "sub()" function was a built-in subtraction function, but it seems like it must be defined in [OpenZeppelin's SafeMath.sol library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.3.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol), because when I comment out the use of SafeMath in this simple example, I get a compiler warning:

[image]

However, when I look in SafeMath.sol, I do not see a single-parameter version of the sub() function. There is only a two-parameter and three-parameter version of sub() defined there:

[image]

Where is this single-parameter version of the sub() function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you have seen in [SafeMath.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol) :

```
function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
     return a - b;
}
```

Is the one that is implicitly called with `block.number.sub(1)`. That is the case because SafeMath.sol is a `library` that is attached to the type `uint256`. You can see it in the Etherenaut challenge contract at this line :

```
using SafeMath for uint256;
```

It is described in [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=using#using-for), for the mismatching number of parameters, this is the relevant part to read :

> The directive using A for B; can be used to attach functions (A) as
> member functions to any type (B). These functions will receive the
> object they are called on as their first parameter (like the self
> variable in Python).

But you can also use the library directly, the two syntax shown in this example are entirely equivalent :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Example {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    function withAttachedFunction() public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 variable = 1;

        return variable.sub(1);
    }

    function withoutAttachedFunction() public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 variable = 1;

        return SafeMath.sub(variable, 1);
    }
}
```

Obviously, using the `variable.sub(...)` syntax is way more convenient, and it is the intended goal of the `using X for Y;` statement.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Looks like a very useful language feature. Thank you!